# Embarcadero RAD Studio & Indy. Error message “Package Size Too Big”

Tags: indy10

I use Embarcadero RAD Studio & Indy and I have a problem.

I am using component IdUDPServer and try to send file via UDP messages.
The file is successfully transferred if it is not large.
However, the error message “Package Size Too Big” appears if the file is large.

My code:

```
FileAPP->ReadBuffer(Buffer, Size);
IdUDPServer1->SendBuffer("10.6.1.255", 34004, RawToBytes(&Buffer, Size));
```

I see two ways to solve this problem:

1) Compose small messages and send these messages in a loop.
This is an easy way to solve the problem, however I will need to fix the remote application.
This is currently difficult. I do not have much time.

2)I want to find a condition in the source code where this error message is generated.
Maybe I can fix the condition and it will work for my specific task.

I have added some pictures. This is all the information that I now have.

Screenshots from help file: [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyPEM.jpg), [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8XOk.jpg), [Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EOYj.jpg)

Error message: [Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAkPU.jpg)

Please help me if you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

"Package Size Too Big" means you tried to send a datagram that is too large for UDP to handle.  UDP has an effective max limit of 65507 bytes of payload data per datagram.  You can't send a large file in a single datagram, it just won't fit.

So yes, you will have to break up your file into smaller chucks that are sent in separate datagrams.  And as such, because UDP is connection-less and does not guarantee delivery, you will also have to solve the issues of lost packets and out-of-order packets.  You will have to put a rolling sequence number inside your packets so that the receiver can save packets in the proper order.  And you will have to implement a re-transmission mechanism to re-send lost packets that the receiver did not receive.

I would suggest not using `TIdUDPClient`/`TIdUDPServer` to implement file transfers manually, if possible.  Indy has `TIdTrivialFTP`/`TIdTrivialFTPServer` components that implement the standardized UDP-based [TFTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350), which handles these kind of details for you.  By default, TFTP has a limit of ~32MB per file (512 bytes per datagram * 65535 datagrams max), but you can increase that limit using the `TIdTrivialFTP.RequestedBlockSize` property to request permission from a TFTP server to send more bytes per datagram.  `RequestedBlockSize` is set to 1500 bytes by default, which can accommodate files up to ~93.7MB in size (though in practice it should not be set higher than 1468 bytes so TFTP datagrams won't exceed the MTU size of Ethernet packets, thus limiting the max file size closer to ~91.7MB).  The `RequestedBlockSize` can be set as high as 65464 bytes per datagram to handle files up to ~3.9GB (at the risk of fragmenting UDP packets at the IP layer).

It is also possible for TFTP to handle unlimited file sizes with smaller datagram sizes, though `TidTrivialFTP`/`TIdTrivialFTPServer` do not currently implement this, because this behavior is not currently standardized in the TFTP protocol, but is commonly implemented as an extension in 3rd party implementations.

Otherwise, you should consider using TCP instead of UDP for your file transfers.  TCP doesn't suffer from these problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I check file integrity using CRC16.
For my task need only UDP because I upload a firmware file to microcontroller.

Comment: @Waleriy TFTP is very common in boot loaders and firmware updaters

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in the following projects.